# Entity class for display and for CRUD operation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using Hibernate 4.1.0 and JPA 2.0

I have an Entity class like the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "EMPLOYEENUMBER")
        private String employeeNumber;

        @Column(name = "EMPLOYEENAME")
        private String employeeName;

        @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT")
        private String dept;
```

/* getters and setters for the above */

...
..

`@Table(name = "V_EMPLOYEES")` Here `V_EMPLOYEES` is a `view` where I am using this to get `employeename` from my lookup table and join with `employeeno`.

I was using the above to display values in datatable and which works fine.

I would like to create a new employee record when user clicks Add button and a popup dialog
where user enters `employeenumber`, `employeestatus`, `employeedepartment` etc.

As I am using a `view` in my `Entity` class, if I want to create a new employee record, should I create a database `view` which can be updatable or create a new `Entity` class reference to `Employee` table? What if I have columns which are not part of datatable for view purpose and I would want to use for create or update record?

What is the best approach and best practice for this?

I am using `EntityManager` for data fetching and for persisting(insert, update and delete)

Any help is highly appeciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given those requirements, I would maintain two separate entities, with common fields pushed up into a mapped superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEmployee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEENUMBER")
    private String employeeNumber;

    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEENAME")
    private String employeeName;

    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT")
    private String dept;

    // Constructor, getters, setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "V_EMPLOYEES")
public class ReadOnlyEmployee extends AbstractEmployee {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee extends AbstractEmployee {
    // Extra mappings here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Extra mapping in Employee class is means all the columns I need to have in other Entity class? If I annot a variable as @Column means I must use that variable in some of a database transaction?

Comment: Yes, all extra mappings for Employees go into that class. I don't follow your second question.

Comment: In ReadOnlyEmployee class, how do I refer employeeNumber,employeeName etc?

Comment: You can reference them via their getter/setters, which will be inherited from the mapper super class.

Comment: My doubt is do I need to add those in ReadOnlyEmployee Entity class? Could you kind enough to show that as example in your answer?

Comment: No, no, common variables with their getters and setters are defined in the mapper super class. The getters/setters are automatically inherited by all the child classes, and using them on instances of the child class (eg `readOnlyEmp.setEmployeeNumber("55")) sets the value for that instance.

Comment: So in my ManagedBean I can do as `readOnlyEmployee.getEmployeeNumber("")` and I do not need to do anything extra in `ReadOnlyEmployee` class? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25017/discussion-between-perception-and-polppan)

Comment: Woa, thats a totally separate issue. @Polppan, better to break it out and ask a separate question.